# Pods error trying to build Expo managed workflow app on SDK 45 using EAS build

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, cocoapods

I'm trying to build my Expo (managed workflow) app using EAS build:

```
eas build -p ios
```

and it's failing with the following error (expo.dev / build details):

```
Installing pods
Using Expo modules
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `livehere`: RNCClipboard, RNCMaskedView, RNDateTimePicker, RNGestureHandler, RNReanimated, RNSVG, RNScreens, RNSentry, react-native-maps, react-native-safe-area-context, and react-native-segmented-control
[Codegen] Generating ./build/generated/ios/React-Codegen.podspec.json
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
[Codegen] Found FBReactNativeSpec
Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `boost` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Adding spec repo `trunk` with CDN `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` named `trunk`.
You can try adding it manually in `/Users/expo/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
pod exited with non-zero code: 1
```

so the problem is in 3 last lines. My eas-cli, expo are updated to latest versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like there's a major CDN outage. https://status.cocoapods.org