# Error running pod install (Flutter android studio)

Tags: flutter, macos, podfile

im having trouble building my flutter project on my mac M1. When i try launching it in android studio im getting the error code 'error running pod install' and when i try opening it in xcode im getting 'module cloud_firestore not found'.

I have tried all the solutions in this thread [How to solve "error running pod install" in flutter on mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135078/how-to-solve-error-running-pod-install-in-flutter-on-mac) but nothing seems to work.

Im having no troble building flutter project without any dependencies but as soon as i add one im getting the error messages mentioned above, any ideas on how i could solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pods error trying to build Expo managed workflow app on SDK 45 using EAS build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72200966/pods-error-trying-to-build-expo-managed-workflow-app-on-sdk-45-using-eas-build)

Comment: Dlete pod lock file then run command update pod from your terminal

Answer (score 0):

I came to this problem as well (Macbook Air M1). I also tried the solution on your mentioned link but failed. However, finally I could solve the problem by following the steps on 'Deploy to iOS Device'

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#install-xcode

1. Run this code on Terminal

   $ sudo gem install cocoapods

   $ sudo gem install ffi -- --enable-libffi-alloc
2. Restart Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

###### I run into these problems all the time on my M1 Pro. They come and go, and you will probably need to do it lots of times.

## You need to do the following:

1. open terminal
2. run 'Flutter clean'.
3. run 'Flutter pub get'.
4. run 'cd ios' (extra: this makes your terminal go into your ios folder in terminal).
5. run 'arch -x86_64 pod install' (extra: since m1 is ARM-processor, it does not allow just "pod install", which the error messages hints to do).
6. just run the app like normal. (extra: it will take 6 minutes to start up now, but it is only the first time after these steps).

Hope this helps. I see it was posted some time ago, so i assume/hope you found a solution.